# Testing Server & Client

Tags: bash, google-chrome, testing, browser, command-line

I want to start testing my server with a couple of clients before moving onto higher numbers.

The current plan right now is just to run tests to check/test latency by writing a script that takes in X amount of seconds that will determine how long the test runs. The script will launch the server and clients. On their end the ping testing code is already in place.

My problem is that while the server is easy to just launch it via a bash script, I don't know any easy way to also launch Chrome and have it go to the webpage.  (the client)

Hoping this is an easy script, my scripting experience is limited :]

Comment: Why use Chrome?  Why not use a text mode browser like lynx or something like curl or wget?

Comment: Testing some webrtc stuff which is only fully supported by Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome will accept URL's on its command-line, like so:

```
chrome http://www.google.com/
```

Comment: Hmm this was the 1st thing I tried & got: "-bash: chrome: command not found" - Got latest version of Google installed (OXS)

Comment: Is chrome on your path in the bash script?  Add an `echo $PATH` before your chrome call.  And are you using chrome or chromium?  And is the executable called `chrome` or `chrome-browser`?

Comment: No I just ran the last command. I am using the latest version of Chrome so it should just be the regular executable. Here's a pic http://imgur.com/9ZkPIkb

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Is chrome on the path for the script or not?  What is the executable called?

Comment: On debian, the executable is called `google-chrome`. Hope that helps.

Comment: No, I gave you the bash command so the path is not specified & the only thing shown as the executable is Google Chrome (OXS)

Comment: But, if you add `echo $PATH` to the bash script just before the call to the Chrome executable like I asked earlier, what path does it output?

Comment: users-mbp-5:pubnubP2P jerry$ echo $PATH chrome www.google.com
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/jerry/bin chrome www.google.com

Comment: That's not what I meant.  In the script, on the line before you try to execute chrome, add the line `echo $PATH`.  What you get on the command-line might not necessarily match.  Also, you need to make sure your chrome executable is actually called `chrome`.